# Convert ASCII number to ASCII Character in C

Tags: c, types, ascii

In C is there a way to convert an ASCII value typed as an int into the the corresponding ASCII character as a char?

Comment: int ia = 65; char ca = (char)ia;

Answer (score 30):

You can assign `int` to `char` directly.

```
int a = 65;
char c = a;
printf("%c", c);
```

In fact this will also work.

```
printf("%c", a);  // assuming a is in valid range
```

Answer (score 18):

If `i` is the `int`, then

```
char c = i;
```

makes it a `char`. You might want to add a check that the value is `<128` if it comes from an untrusted source. This is best done with `isascii` from `<ctype.h>`, if available on your system (see @Steve Jessop's comment to this answer).

Comment: `isascii` is a Posix function, not standard C. MS apparently supports it too (but deprecated), so that covers most implementations.

Comment: @Steve, thanks for the correction, you're right. I also misspelled `ctype.h` as `ctypes.h`.

Answer (score 3):

If the number is stored in a string (which it would be if typed by a user), you can use `atoi()` to convert it to an integer.

An integer can be assigned directly to a character. A character is different mostly just because how it is interpreted and used.

```
char c = atoi("61");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char A;
printf("ASCII value of %c = %d", c, c);
```

In this program, the user is asked to enter a character. The character is stored in variable c.
When `%d` format string is used, `65` (the ASCII value of `A`) is displayed.
When `%c` format string is used, `A` itself is displayed.

Output:
`ASCII value of A = 65`

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
int d;
int main(void){
    string a = get_string("enter your word: ");
    int i = 0;
    while(a[i] != '\0'){
        printf("%i ", a[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).