# Removing digits and all punctuation except apostrophe from a string in C

Tags: c, string, char

I'm writing some code that takes a string as an argument and makes alpha character lowercase, removes digits (012...9), and removes all punctuation except apostrophes. Here's my code so far:

```
void stripLower(char* str) {
    int strLen = strlen(str);
    char* temp[strLen];
    char apos = (char)"39";

    for(int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
        if(isupper(str[i])){
            str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
        } else if(isdigit(str[i])) {
            str[i] = (char)"0";
        } else if(ispunct(str[i])){
            /*if((strcmp(str[i], apos)) == 0){

            } else {
                str[i] = (char)"0";
            }*/
        }
    }

    /*for(int i = 0; i < strLen; i++){
        str[i] = temp[i];
    } */
}
```

My first question is am I correctly removing the digits from the string? My other question is how can I get rid of all the punctuation except apostrophes? I commented out some code I tried because it would prevent the rest of my code from running correctly.

Comment: `char apos = (char)"39"` nope. nope. nope.

Comment: Things are not like this. You just can't typecast a string ("39") to a char this way. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660145/convert-ascii-number-to-ascii-character-in-c

Comment: Stack overflow is not code review or debugging site.

Comment: What did you find out when you tested and debugged it?

Comment: You seem generally pretty confused about C strings and the difference between `char *` and `char` as well as string literals and char literals.  I'd recommend doing some more reading on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing strings and characters. A character literal is enclosed in `'`. A string literal is enclosed in `"` and is an array of characters.

e.g.:

```
"This is a string literal"
'c' // this is character
```

To test if a char is not `z` for instance, you write:

```
char c = ...;    
if (c == 'z')
```

For special characters, like `'`, new line, tab etc. you have to escape them like this:

```
char c1 = '\'' // this is a ' character
char c2 = '\t' // this is a tab character
```

`strcpm` is for comparing strings. If you want to compare characters, `==` are what you need, as I've shown above.

---

Your function can be written simply as this:

```
int strip(char* str)
{
    int from, to;       
    for (from = 0, to = 0; str[from] != '\0'; ++from) {
        if (!isdigit(str[from]) && (!ispunct(str[from]) || str[from] == '\'')) {
            str[to] = tolower(str[from]);
            ++to;
        }
    }
    str[to] = '\0';
}
```

example input and output:

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "This is 'Sparta'! The 200. I ,think,";
    strip(str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
this is 'sparta' the  i think
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement is wrong on multiple levels.

```
char apos=(char)"39";
```

This assigns apos to be a pointer value (because the result of a string literal in C is a `const char *`), but truncated to fit in `char`.  The warning (error?) you compiler gave before adding the cast should have been the hint that this line was wrong.

The C syntax for a character literal is a single-quoted value.  To escape the `'` character, you use a backslash like so:

```
char apos = '\'';
```

Then you can compare this value for direct equality (i.e. `==`) rather than using `strcmp`, which takes a string, not a `char`.

Although in this case, I would probably leave out the local variable `apos` entirely and either directly compare as follows:

```
 if((strcmp(str[i], '\'')) == 0){ /* your code here*/ }
```

Or if you don't like the use of a char literal, use a macro (which I feel is probably unnecessary obfuscation in this case):

```
#define CHAR_APOS ('\'')
if((strcmp(str[i], '\'')) == 0){ /* your code here*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
 str[i] = (char)"0";
```

Won't remove digits.

If you mean shifting the whole string to the left by "removing" a character, below code will serve your purpose

Functions are a part of [a BSD licensed string processing library, called zString](https://github.com/fnoyanisi/zString).

```
int zstring_search_chr(char *token,char s){
    if (!token || s=='\0')
        return 0;

    for (;*token; token++)
        if (*token == s)
            return 1;

    return 0;
}

char *zstring_remove_chr(char *str,char *bad) {
    char *src = str , *dst = str;
    while(*src)
        if(zstring_search_chr(bad,*src))
            *src++;
        else
            *dst++ = *src++;  /* assign first, then incement */

    *dst='\0';
    return str;
}
```

And a usage example

```
  Example Usage
      char s[]="this is a trial string to test the function.";
      char *d=" .";
      printf("%s\n",zstring_remove_chr(s,d));

  Example Output
      thisisatrialstringtotestthefunction
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you can't just typecast a string into a character. In this case, I would just do:

```
char apos = '\''; //a symbol between apostrophes is a character and between quotation marks is a string
```

or if you want to use the decimal number that corresponds to the symbol in the ASCII table you can do:

```
char apos = 39;
```