# Can you convert ASCII number to a character in C?

Tags: c, performance, types, ascii

I have read the following question entry: [Convert ASCII number to ASCII Character in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660145/convert-ascii-number-to-ascii-character-in-c)

All the answers in it required saving data (`char`...). So my question is whether you can convert `ASCII` number to `ASCII`Character without saving any data on the device running the code?

**Clarification:** the conversion I'm talking about is that in machine syntax, `"a"` equals to `97` (decimal), and if I have the number `97`, how can I translate it into 'human' syntax (into `"a"`).

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by ASCII number. If you mean ASCII code, then basically the code *is* the value of the char variable character.

Comment: The `char` value 97 is _never_ an "a" glyph until it needs to be drawn somewhere. What conversion are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C characters *are* numbers, it's a matter of their *interpretation*.

Any small number can be interpreted as a character, ASCII or whatever is the character encoding standard on your system. Conversely, a `char` could be interpreted as a small number without storing it.

Here is an example:

```
int num;
scanf("%d", &num);
printf("Number %d corresponds to character '%c'\n", num, num);
```

The program reads a number, and passes it to `printf` to interpret twice - first time as an integer number, and the second time as a character.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/1A0jrF)

Comment: If you can reference then number in some manner, you can do it the exact same way, regardless whether the number is user input, or some stray byte the cache dragged home.

Answer (score 2):

As it was well said by [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight), the characters are just numbers, bytes, which can contain any value in its 8 bits storage.
The value can be interpreted as ASCII character, unsigned or unsigned value.

For example value `0x31` can be interpreted as printable character `'1'` or decimal value `49`. `97` can be number or character `a`.

```
char str[2];

str[0] = 97;
str[1] = '\0';

printf("0x31 = %d and %c\n",0x31,0x31);
printf("97 = %s %d %c \n",str, str[0], str[0] );
```

Prints:

```
0x31 = 49 and 1                                                                                                                           
97 = a 97 a
```