# how can i safely convert an ascii integer back to its associated ascii character using curses in c++?

Tags: c++11, type-conversion, ascii, curses

I have not been able to find a reliable solution for my problem, what i'm simply trying to do is create some function which:

- takes an rows and columns position in the terminal.
- calls **mvinch(window_object , rows, cols)**, which returns an unsigned int which corresponds to the character in the terminal at that position.
- returns the ascii character associated with that unsigned int, effectively casting it back to a char.

Here is an example of my code in c++11:

```
char Kmenu::getChrfromW(size_t const y, size_t const x,
                        bool const save_cursor) const {
  size_t curr_y, curr_x;
  getyx(_win, curr_y, curr_x);
  char ich = mvwinch(_win, y, x);
  char ch = ich;
  if (save_cursor)
    wmove(_win, curr_y, curr_x);
  return ch;
}
```

If for example the character in the terminal  at position 2,3 is the letter 'a', i want this function to return the letter 'a'.

I tried the solution described here:

[Convert ASCII number to ASCII Character in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660145/convert-ascii-number-to-ascii-character-in-c)

which effectively casts an integer as char.

unfortunately what i get back is still the integer: testing with a screen filled with 'w's, i get back the integer 119.

the man page for the curses function mvwinch() describes the function to return *chtype*, which the compiler recognises as unsigned int.

Is there a built in a curses function which gives the char back directly without casting to unsigned int, or some other way i can achieve this?

Edit: ch to ich, as in the actual code

Comment: 1. For the benefit of readers of your code - please try to make your names more readable and dnt nm thm lk ts. Its vry dfclt t rd. 2. Your "get char from window" function, assuming that's what it is, seems to have side-effects (`wmove()`) - confusing!. 3. You're declaring `ch` twice. Perhaps the first variable is `ich`?

Comment: There is no such thing as "ASCII integer". Integers are integers. ASCII characters are abstract entities, they do not exist in C code directly. They are represented by integers. The character `'w'` is represented by the integer 119. As far as C is concerned, `'w'` **is** 119 (if your character set is ASCII of course).

Comment: @einpoklum yes thats right its meant to be ich, thats what it actually is in the code. the wmove call is something unrelated. You make a good point about readability, i will take that into account, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `chtype` contains a character along with other data.  The [`curses.h`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/5496cf574fca72e1c697d5f4031cbd4428260bb8/include/curses.h.in#L1109) header has several symbols which are useful for extracting those bits.  If you mask it with `A_CHARTEXT` and cast that to a `char`, you will get a character:

```
char c = (char)((A_CHARTEXT) & n);
```

Your example should not compile, since it declares `ch` twice.  You may have meant this:

```
char Kmenu::getChrfromW(size_t const y, size_t const x,
                        bool const save_cursor) const {
  int curr_y, curr_x;  // size_t is inappropriate...
  getyx(_win, curr_y, curr_x);
  char ch = (char)((A_CHARTEXT) & mvwinch(_win, y, x));
  // char ch = ich;
  if (save_cursor)
    wmove(_win, curr_y, curr_x);
  return ch;
}
```

The manual page for [`mvwinch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inch.3x.html) mentions the `A_CHARTEXT` mask in the [*Attributes*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inch.3x.html#h3-Attributes) section, assuming the reader is familiar with things like that:

```
   The following bit-masks may  be  AND-ed  with  characters  returned  by
   winch.

   A_CHARTEXT     Bit-mask to extract character
   A_ATTRIBUTES   Bit-mask to extract attributes
   A_COLOR        Bit-mask to extract color-pair field information
```

Comment: Hi, i have tried your suggestion and casted the return value of ```mvwinch```, unfortunately testing this on a window filled with 'w's returns still its integer: 119

Comment: I suspect your program has a problem in another place :-)

Comment: yes the first ch was meant to be ich, as in the actual code, thats my mistake. I was checking the return value of the function by outputting it back to the terminal using ```mvwprintw```. It turns out that  casting as a string using ```std::to_string(ch)```, outputs 119. However if i output the return value to screen as a ```char *``` it returns ```wP   ^W^?```. essentially w with some extra unwanted characters. This is a pretty much workable solution, Thanks!